# Designing a Requirement Satisfaction structure

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to implement a 'Requirements' type system into a program. It seemed pretty simple in my head, but actually making it abstract enough to be useful is proving more difficult than anticipated.

Here is what I am trying to do ...

```
enum Condition {
 Not, Exists, Exceeds
}

abstract class Requirement { 
  // base class
  Condition Condition { get; set; }
}

class ScoreRequirement : Requirement {
  // a specific 'score' is required
}
class TraitRequirement : Requirement {
  // a specific 'trait' is required
}
class SatisfyingObject {
  // this is the class that has to satisfy the requirements
  IDictionary<Trait, int> Traits { get; set; }
}
```

If I know the exact thing that has to be satisfied in code-time, this is very simple. But the goal is to let people add requirements later. There will be other types that derive from `Requirement`, as well.

So a requirement might work like this ...

```
var obj = new Item { 
 Requirements = new List<Requirement> {
   new ScoreRequirement { Trait = "One", Score = 2, Condition = Condition.Exceeds }
 }
}
```

So the concept seems pretty simple. You would call upon an object..

```
var satisfying = // get the satisfying object;

if( satisfying.Satisfies( obj.Requirements ) )
 return true;
```

The problem I am running into is really how to code the `Satisfies` method - in specific I am not sure how to relate it to the `Condition` parameter. I'd like people to be able to set up some fairly generic 'requirements', but the logic behind this is very confusing to me. Since the requirements are not known at design time, I cannot really hard code any of them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't a learning project than I would highly recommend you look at using something that is already built for this:

1. [EntLib Validation Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664356%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx)
2. [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)
3. Anything built on top of the [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)

***If however you are doing this as a simple learning project***, than you have 2 basic approaches you could take:

1. Reflection based
2. Delegate based

Of the two, delegate based is going to be much simpler to implement, but less flexible. I have implemented this pattern several times and the concept is simple. Here is about the most basic concept you can get.

```
public interface IRuleDefinition
{
    String PropertyName { get; }
    String Message { get; }
}

public class ValidationRule<T>: IRuleDefinition
{
    public String PropertyName { get; private set; }
    public String Message { get; private set; }

    private Func<T, Boolean> _isValidDelegate;

    public ValidationRule(Func<T, Boolean> isValidDelegate, String propertyName, String message)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        Message = message;
        _isValidDelegate = isValidDelegate;
    }

    public Boolean IsValid(T objToValidate)
    {
        return _isValidDelegate(objToValidate);
    }
}

public class Validator<T>
{
    private List<ValidationRule<T>> _validationRules = new List<ValidationRule<T>>();

    public void AddRule(Func<T, Boolean> isValidDelegate, String propertyName = null, String message = null)
    {
        _validationRules.Add(new ValidationRule<T>(isValidDelegate, propertyName, message));
    }

    public Boolean IsValid(T objToValidate)
    {
        return _validationRules.Any(vr => vr.IsValid(objToValidate));
    }

    public IEnumerable<IRuleDefinition> GetViolations(T objToValidate)
    {
        return _validationRules
             .Where(vr => !vr.IsValid(objToValidate))
             .Cast<IRuleDefinition>();
    }
}
```

You can use it in code like this:

```
var myObj = new MyObject{ Name = "Josh", Age = 29 };

var myObjValidator = new Validator<MyObject>();

myObjValidator.AddRule(
    obj => !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(obj.Name), 
    "Name", "Name is required!");

myObjValidator.AddRule(
    obj => obj.Age < 99,
    "Age", "Age must be less than 99");

myObjValidator.AddRule(
    obj => obj.Name == "Logan" && obj.Age < 29,
    message: "RUN!!!");

if(!myObjValidator.IsValid(myObj))
{
    foreach(var violation in myObjValidator.GetViolations(myObj))
        Console.WriteLine("Property: {0}, Message: {1}", 
            violation.PropertyName, violation.Message);
}
```

Now, this was all from memory, so there <strike>may be some</strike> are probably coding/compiler errors in all this, but hopefully you get the general idea.

Again, if this isn't a learning project, [then don't reinvent the wheel unless you are planning to learn more about wheels :)](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels.html)

Comment: Thanks! I will look at your example for a bit and try to understand it. The reason I cannot use the given examples is because the rules have to be stored in a database, and therefore they must be serializable - and they are also not known at runtime. They are added to the system by the end-user.

Comment: @Ciel, then you should probably look into the EntLib validation block as you can have validation rules stored in areas besides code. It has a way to do this via the Config file out of the box, but that can be extended to use the database with some work. Any more advanced than that, and you need to look into using a full blown business rules engine. Most of those have a pretty steep learning curve as well.

Comment: Also, your code compiled with only one change. The usage of `AddRule` with the Name didn't work right away. Pretty good code for 'from memory'!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend determining the bare minimum scope required for specifying requirements and start with that, to see how complex the design becomes.  If you're finding that even the minimum scope leads to a lot of complexity or if you can't even get a grasp on what the minimum scope would be, then you may want to look into a more flexible approach, like hosting a scripting language to be used for expressing your constraints.  There are a wide range of available libraries to support this and they will be cheaper to support/maintain than something you've created and evolved yourself in an effort to provide an 'easy' way of setting constraints.

Keep it simple if you can, but if it really does need to be complicated, try to find something already built and tested as a foundation, so as to reduce the burden of the complexity.

Comment: I've looked around for such things but have not found anything. Do you know of anything in specific that might be a good place to start?

Comment: Here's one option that lets you embed/execute C# scripts into your application: http://www.csscript.net/

Comment: Hrnm... hosting a scripting language would not let me serialize the constraints to be saved in a database, though, which I will have to do.

Comment: The constraints would be expressed as a function in the scripting language, which is simply a string, so it's easy to save to the database.  It's definitely not a trivial solution and I wouldn't recommend it unless you really need the flexibility.